# Shorten URL to only include get request?

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, http

How do I make it so that my page redirects a url like: https://mysite/12345 to https://mysite/image.php?id=12345

I want to be able to shorten urls to only include the get request. Is this achievable through php or a .htaccess file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you would do this using the `.htaccess` file, with entries like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)(/?)$ image.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

So you can write your urls in the format:
`https://mysite/12345`

To go the other way and have a url such as `https://mysite/image.php?id=12345` redirect to `https://mysite/12345`

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(?:image\.php)?\?id=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L,NE]
```